# How do I separate my melted rock candies?

Tags: candy, melting

I recently bought a a jar of rock candies and after one night, they have melted and all stuck together. How do I separate them again to eat them? (I tried freezing, it didn’t work!)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a picture so we can get a measure of the level to which they are stuck together?

Comment: we need to know what type of container, can you remove the candy from the container, and what things you have tried so far (other than freezing).

Answer (score 3):

If you can get them out of the jar, I would suggest a hammer.

Put them in a plastic bag and whack them with the hammer.

You might be able to use a knife (carefully) to pry them apart depending on much they are stuck together.

Comment: That is why I say "if you can get them out of the jar"

Comment: ok, I overfocused on hammer, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can try filling jar with water (warm water is more effective) so they start dissolving and unstuck. Then they can be dried outside of the jar.